# AVSpeechSynthesizer error: An AVSpeechUtterance shall not be enqueued twice

Tags: ios, swift, avspeechsynthesizer

I am stuck a little bit.

Here is my code:

```
let speaker = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
var playQueue = [AVSpeechUtterance]() // current queue
var backedQueue = [AVSpeechUtterance]() // queue backup

...

func moveBackward(_ currentUtterance:AVSpeechUtterance) {
    speaker.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)
    let currentIndex = getCurrentIndexOfText(currentUtterance)
    // out of range check was deleted
    let previousElement = backedQueue[currentIndex-1]
    playQueue.insert(previousElement, at: 0)
    for utterance in playQueue {
        speaker.speak(utterance) // error here
    }
}
```

According to the docs `AVSpeechSynthesizer.stopSpeaking(at:)`:

> Stopping the synthesizer cancels any further speech; in constrast with
>   when the synthesizer is paused, speech cannot be resumed where it left
>   off. **Any utterances yet to be spoken are removed from the
>   synthesizer’s queue**.

I always get the error(AVSpeechUtterance shall not be enqueued twice), when I insert an AVSpeechUtterance in the `AVSpeechSynthesizer` queue. But it should stop according to the doc.

Comment: What are you planning to do exactly with your 'moveBackward' method ?

Comment: I was trying to play previous element from backedQueue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When stopping the player, the utterances are definitely removed from the queue.

However, in your `moveBackward` function, you insert another `AVSpeechUterrance` at `playQueue[0]` whose complete array represents the player queue.

Assuming the stops happens with `currentIndex = 2`, the following snapshots prove that **the same object is injected twice in the queue**:

- Copy `backedQueue[1]` that is a copy of `playQueue[1]` *(same memory address)*.
  [image]
- Insert `backedQueue[1]` at `playQueue[0]` *(former `playQueue[1]` becomes new `playQueue[2]`)*.
  [image]

Unfortunately, as the system indicates, *AVSpeechUtterance shall not be enqueued twice* and that's exactly what you're doing here: objects at playQueue indexes 0 and 2 **have the same memory address**.

The last loop after inserting the new object at index 0 asks the speech synthesizer to put all the utterances in its all new queue... and two of them are the same.

Instead of copying the `playedQueue` into the `backedQueue` *(both contain the same memory addresses to their objects)* OR appending the same utterance in both arrays, I suggest to **create different utterance instances** to be put as follows:

```
    for i in 1...5 {

        let stringNb = "number " + String(i) + " of the speech synthesizer."
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: stringNb)
        playQueue.append(utterance)

        let utteranceBis = AVSpeechUtterance(string: stringNb)
        backedQueue.append(utteranceBis)
    }
```

Following this piece of advice, you shouldn't meet the error *AVSpeechUtterance shall not be enqueued twice*.